# Python Reading Google Docs formated CSV file as UTF-8

Tags: python, csv

I have made a spreadsheet in google docs with a row with the following text: "test æøå"
In google docs i exported it as CSV.

Using Python 2.6.5 i want to read this document in so that i get the text "test æøå" and not "test √¶√∏√•"

How can i achive this?

Link to the CSV file: http://www.filedropper.com/googledocs
or
Hexdump: 74 65 73 74 20 C3 A6 C3 B8 C3 A5

Comment: I guess the output encoding depends on your terminal locale.

I've tried the script below with your input file and it produced expected result:

#!/usr/bin/python  

import csv
    
    f = open('google_docs.csv')
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    
    for l in reader:
        print ','.join(l)

Comment: LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Comment: thanks alot! I wonder why it did not work with min (just UTF-8)

Comment: Could be because 'UTF-8' locale is not present in your system so it falls back to the default one.